# How to load data outside Django view?

Tags: django, postgresql

If i have some Django views like 'first', 'second' and so on, and i want to load some data outside this views but use it inside views.

Here is an example to understand my idea.

```
#function execution time is long, that is why i want to laod it only once when run programm.

fetched_data_from_postgres = some function which load data from postgres and return list with postgres data

def first(request):
    #and the i want to use that previous value in all my views
    fetched_data_from_postgres = do something
    return HttpResponse("first VIEW")

def second(request):
    #and the i want to use that previous value in all my views
    fetched_data_from_postgres = do something
    return HttpResponse("secondVIEW")

def third(request):
    #and the i want to use that previous value in all my views
    fetched_data_from_postgres = do something
    return HttpResponse("third VIEW")
```

---

this aproach working well when i run my django project like this `python manage.py runserver` but when i run with gunicorn or wsgi when i can specify workers count then when worker changes then this variable is lost and need to refresh page to get this previous worker to get that data. It's ridiculous.

Or maybe there is some other aproach to do this job?

Comment: Have you thought about caching this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach doesn't work when you start project locally with `python manage.py runserver`, it only works once, when project starts, and then you need to reload the project every time. This is because everything in `any_views.py` loads only once, when project starts, except your functions. So you have to restart your project, in order to refresh your `fetched_data_from_postgres` variable.

The better approach is to create a script `fetch_script.py`, move your function `some function which load data from postgres and return list with postgres data` inside it, and call it inside of `views.py`, not outside.

Comment: thanks for the replay. But if we are talking about memory? This cache takes as much memory as this variable? If variable takes 1GB of ram then this cache takes also 1GB? Or there is some different logic? @oruchkin

Comment: Dmiich, yes this is correct, but if you do your logic inside functions, after it's done it's logic it would release all RAM it used. If you need to cache it, you might do as scūriolus answerd

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to avoid loading your data several times and to prevent this function `fetched_data_from_postgres` to run twice is to **use a cache framework** alongside Django. Check the documentation for more details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/

It's relatively easy to set up and it should perfectly address your problem. If you feel it like overkill, then the question is do you really need speed? Are you sure you're not trying to prematurely optimize?